# How to sign in a Android app if computer is not working?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, apk

I want to update the Android App but the computer in which I worked earlier, is currently not working. Some how I got the android key from the computer but the system is not working. Can I sign in the android app with other computer with this key? Will Google play accept the updated signed apk from other computer?

Comment: Computer matters not. Only the keystore file important is.

Comment: You can use another computer but you know your password of release apk and keystore path

Comment: solved the issue, thankss

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible. The only thing you need to be able to sign an apk is the correct Android key and the corresponding passwords. Of course you'll also need Android Studio and Java on your new computer, but I assume that won't be a problem.